# Github Desktop has stopped working (after updating to windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, git, windows-10-upgrade, github

After updating to windows 10:

Everytime i run Github Desktop the error "Github has stopped working" pops up.
 Microsoft Visual Studio debug retrieves this message:

"System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Additional information: A procedure imported by 'CefSharp.Core.dll' could not be loaded.
"

I have tried clean installs of Github Desktop with no improvements.
I googled the CefSHarp.Core.dll file, but I found no fixes as I could understand.

Any ideas?

Note: Interestingly enough this issue only occurs on my stationary and not my laptop (both have been updated to windows 10).